RecycleView not showing
I am developing an android Studio app, and i want to show with a recycleview the pets that the user has in his profile, i tried the same recyclerview in another empty activity and it shows, so the problem has to be in the xml file but i cant find it, if someone had this problem and can help me, i will be forever gratitude.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PerfilUsuario">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_superior_perfil"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_superior_perfil"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_inferior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fotoPerfil"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nombreUsuario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nombre de usuario"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tituloDatosPersonales"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Datos personales"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/correo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Correo: "
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tituloDatosPersonales"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/telefono"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Teléfono: "
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/correo"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fechaRegistro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fecha de registro: "
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/telefono"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/valoracion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fechaRegistro" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/biografia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Biografía: "
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/valoracion"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/biografia" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tituloMascotas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Mascotas"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMascotas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tituloMascotas"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/añadirMascota"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerViewMascotas">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icons8_add_50" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Añadir mascota"
                    android:textColor="@color/texto"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_right_24" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_inferior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


The FrameLayout fragment_container is displayed over the RecyclerView and set to match_parent in both directions. Width and Height should be 0dp for constraints to take effect. Also, do you really need that much nesting? A RecyclerView inside a ScrollView?

Set the height of the recyclerview to 0dp.
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView     android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMascotas"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="0dp"     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tituloMascotas"     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/añadirMascota"     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
